# Handling all errors in the same way

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, exception

I have created simple REST API with one entity

```
@Entity
public class Note {
@JsonIgnore
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

@NotBlank(message = "Given title is empty")
private String title;

@NotNull(message = "Given content is null")
private String content;
```

I used custom exception handler

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomGlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

@Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, 
HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
    Map<String,Object> body = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    body.put("timestamp", new Date());
    body.put("status",status.value());

    List<String> errors = ex.getBindingResult()
            .getFieldErrors()
            .stream()
            .map(DefaultMessageSourceResolvable::getDefaultMessage)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    body.put("errors", errors);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(body,headers,status);
}
}
```

Exceptions thrown from Hibernate validator looks now like this:

```
{
"timestamp": "2021-04-24T21:43:58.678+00:00",
"status": 400,
"errors": [
    "Given title is empty"
]
}
```

But other exceptions which are thrown by me look like this

```
{
"timestamp": "2021-04-24T21:46:05.576+00:00",
"status": 400,
"error": "Bad Request",
"message": "Task with given id does not exist",
"path": "/api/notes/2"
 }
```

How can I handle them in the same way as those from Hibernate Validator, do I need other custom validator ?

Answer (score 0):

```java
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.lang.Nullable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomGlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleExceptionInternal(Exception ex, @Nullable Object body, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        Map<String, Object> _body = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        _body.put("timestamp", new Date());
        _body.put("status", status.value());
        _body.put("errors", ex.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(body,headers,status);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler()
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleConflict(RuntimeException ex, WebRequest request) {
        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, ex.getMessage(), new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, request);
    }
}
```